# Ubuntu 16.04 cryptswap

Tags: 16.04, encryption

I have a new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and when installing I chose to encrypt my home directory.

However when Ubuntu loads up I get the following: -

Enter passphrase for disk cryptswap1 on none!

Been googling around and can't find out exactly what this is. Could someone explain what's happened here? Is that my swap partition being encrypted? What does the none mean?

If I just hit enter Ubuntu loads fine and I can't see anything that would indicate a problem.

Thanks!

EDIT

`cat /proc/meminfo` shows 
`SwapTotal: 32969212 kB`

`cat /etc/fstab` shows 
`# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation #UUID=ea7af1d8-3253-4e22-9620-d460ebf86dec none swap sw 0 0 /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`

so it looks like there's swap space there

Comment: I've had this problem before.  If you check `cat /proc/meminfo` or `top`, you will probably find that you have no swap space.  There are two solutions: (1) you can remake your swap without encryption or (2) diagnose the ecryptfs problem.  Start by posting the relevant line from `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin. I've added the outputs of what you suggested to my post.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working.  Not sure what's up.   I've had to wipe and remake cryptswap on occasion; and that's a last resort option.  You might try `journalctl -b0 | grep cryptswap1` to get a clue from the kernel.  FYI, the 18.04 installer no longer offers the encrypted home option using ecryptfs-utils. Rather, one uses a LUKS for full-disk encryption with a swap file (which is therefore automatically encrypted).  Of course, if you already have ecryptfs, you can upgrade to 18.04 without a problem.

Comment: Tried an apt-get upgrade last night and it kept asking "Enter passphrase for disk cryptswap1 on none!" during that process but since then it no longer asks when booting. Chalking it down to something odd with 16.04